# Word Embeddings on Mobiles (Android, iOS)

Tags: android, ios, machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp

I would like to use Word Embeddings (aka GloVe) in my Mobile (Android, iOS) app. Nevertheless, the pre-trained weights file is large (starting from 100MB and up to 800MB). what are the generally accepted approaches for storing and using large pre-trained models on Mobiles?

Comment: from what i know its just a neural network right? cant we use TFlite or isnt it same as running python code https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/neuralnetworks

Comment: I have developed a small library `glove-android` which provides 50D GloVe embeddings for Android projects. Check the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/shubham0204/glove-android).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretrained embeddings have massive vocabularies, and while you don't need to store each word's vector you do need the actual string to determine the input to the model. You'll either need to restrict the vocabulary or allow users to query your model over the web. If you need the model on-device make sure you load it asynchronously, since it will hang your threads.